# Rails 4: form object for update action for 2 models

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form object that handles 2 associated objects. I'm trying to get some validation working on the form object, but am not having much success.

I think the issue is that the attributes I'm validating are delegated to the model objects, but I'm not sure how else to handle this situation: when the form is displayed, these attributes need to pull from the actual models to show the values on the form in edit mode, but when I update the form, I need to validate the submitted parameters, not the values being pulled from the models themselves.

One thought I have is using a `EditBorrowerForm` object that pulls attributes from associated models and a `UpdateBorrowerForm` that performs all the validations and updates the models.  But that seems like a lot of extra work for something trivial.

I've seen a lot of form objects used for CREATE actions (where you only validate fields before passing them to the models), but haven't seen any good examples of UPDATE actions (where you need to both pull fields from models as well as update them).

Here are the models I'm working with:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :borrowers
end

class Borrower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

And my form object:

```
class BorrowerForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :client, :borrower

  delegate :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, to: :client
  delegate :citizenship, :marital_status, to: :borrower

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :citizenship, presence: true

  def initialize(borrower)
    @borrower = borrower
    @client = @borrower.client
  end

  def update_attributes(params)
    # Never validates properly...
    if valid?
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        borrower.update_attributes(params.slice(:citizenship, :marital_status)
        client.update_attributes(params.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth)
      end

      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

And the controller:

```
class BorrowersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @borrower = BorrowerForm.new(Borrower.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @borrower = BorrowerForm.new(Borrower.find(params[:id])

    if @borrower.update_attributes(params)
      redirect_to :index
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```